# max value of an input 999999, but allows pasting more than that in IE broswer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have a maximum value in an input **999999**. I used the `onkeypress="return IsCurrencyNoMinus(event, this, 0, 999999, false);"` and it works perfectly in firfox and doesn't allow pasting more than that, but in IE  it allows pasting more than the value above. should i just use `maxlenght="6"`

Comment: well, i mean, i'd suggest if you were going to use `maxlenght="6"`, you should instead use `maxlength="6"`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number might be more appropriate with min and max.

Comment: @Kevin B Sorry for the mistype, but would that allow more than 999999? Not sure because the maxlength count digits but not value. I'm sorry I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use min and max property for IE 10:

```
<input title="Enter an even number" type="number" min="0" max="100" step="2">
```

Here useful polyfill: https://github.com/jonstipe/number-polyfill

Comment: In case it is not obvious, the `title` and `step` are examples of optional attributes, but do not apply specifically to the original question as posted.

Comment: Polyfill, might be overkill, depending on how old a browser you have to support (IE 9, for example) http://caniuse.com/#search=number%20input%20type